# Remote desktop not continuing to run programs when I close it

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services, remote-desktop-services

I am using remote desktop to install and setup Windows Server 2008 R2. I'm having an issue when copying hundreds of GBs of files to the server. When I close remote desktop it is supposed to keep my session running and the copying running.

The problem I'm having is that once I close RDC the coping and the running apps just stop.  I am not using the logoff, instead I am just closing out of RDC.  It says my apps will keep running that everything will be the same when I log back in, but when I do, everything quit.

Any insight?

Comment: The server might be configured to not allow disconnected sessions (so you get logged off as soon as you close the RDP application).

Answer (score 5):

If you are copying the files via a mapping to `\\tsclient\c` (or whichever drive on your client you are transferring from) then the copy will terminate because the connection to `\\tsclient` is lost when you close the RDP client.  Instead, create a mapping to `\\<computer_name>\<share>` and transfer from there.  In this case the copy should continue.

Also, ensure that you do not have a timeout configured for RDP sessions which forces the session to terminate after a period of inactivity.  In the Terminal Services Configuration tool, check the settings for the RDP connection to ensure that "End a disconnected session" is disabled, and that the "Active session limit" and "Idle session limit" are also disabled.